# sapply returns characters instead of factor

Tags: r, sapply

I make a dataframe

```
x<-data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:100,20,rep=TRUE)))
time<-rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times=5)
id<-rep(c("WT", "KO"), each=10)
df<-cbind(id, time,x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to make everything numeric in order to scale the data for an heatmap but sapply returns id and time as characters instead of factor.

```
sapply(df, class)

   id         time            X1           X2         X3          X4         X5           
"character" "character"   "integer"   "integer"   "integer"   "integer"  "integer"   

   X6           X7
"integer"   "integer"
```

I have no idea what to do now,  can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: how do you want to convert a character to numeric??

Comment: Try `data.frame(id, time, x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `data.frame` instead of `cbind` to get 'id' and 'time' as `factor` columns as the default option is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`.

```
df <- data.frame(id, time, x)
sapply(df, class)
#  id      time        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6 
#"factor"  "factor" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" 
#    X7 
#"integer"
```